# Derivative of $f(x)=Ax$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let A be a matrix and $f:\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ with $f(x)=Ax$. What is the derivative of this function. How do we apply differentiation to any function, which is not elementary? Is there a definition like $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}$ which does not hold in this case of course.

Comment: See [derivatives of multivariate functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_of_several_real_variables#Partial_derivatives) and [derivatives of vector valued functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Vector-valued_functions) for a formal definition.

Comment: https://youtu.be/wCZ1VEmVjVo is a video I recently encountered that might explain it for you.